# How to group colllection by children in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a collection "features" that each has a "feature group". 1 Feature `belongsToMany` feature groups.

1 feature `belongsToMany` cars, so it's a subcollection on itself. In my car view I want to group the features. How would I go about this?

An **example collection**:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "group_id":1,
      "name":"metallic",
      "pivot":{
         "car_id":1,
         "feature_id":1
      },
      "group":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"paint"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "group_id":1,
      "name":"blue",
      "pivot":{
         "car_id":1,
         "feature_id":2
      },
      "group":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"paint"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "group_id":2,
      "name":"gps",
      "pivot":{
         "car_id":1,
         "feature_id":5
      },
      "group":{
         "id":2,
         "name":"interior"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "group_id":2,
      "name":"leather seats",
      "pivot":{
         "car_id":1,
         "feature_id":6
      },
      "group":{
         "id":2,
         "name":"interior"
      }
   }
]
```

The **desired result** would be something like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"paint",
      "features":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "group_id":1,
            "name":"metallic"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "group_id":1,
            "name":"blue"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"interior",
      "features":[
         {
            "id":5,
            "group_id":2,
            "name":"gps"
         },
         {
            "id":6,
            "group_id":2,
            "name":"leather seats"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

In my **Controller** I am trying to create a new collection, using `each()` loop and `mergeRecursive()`, like this:

```
$car = Car::where('slug', $slug)->first()->load('features.group');

$newCollection = collect(["group 1" => "feature 1"]);

$car->features->each(function ($item, $key) use($newCollection) {
    $current = collect([
        $item->group->name => $item->name,
    ]);
    $newCollection->mergeRecursive($current);
});

dd($newCollection);

return view('pages.car', [
    'car' => $car,
    'features' => $newCollection,
]);
```

The only data in my collection is the dummy data I instantiated it with. What am I missing?

Any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution. No need to loop over the collection to create a new collection. There is a collection method [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) that does the trick:

`$myCollection->groupBy('group_id');` returns this:

```
{
   "1":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "group_id":1,
         "name":"metallic",
         "pivot":{
            "car_id":1,
            "feature_id":1
         },
         "group":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"paint"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "group_id":1,
         "name":"blue",
         "pivot":{
            "car_id":1,
            "feature_id":2
         },
         "group":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"paint"
         }
      }
   ],
   "2":[
      {
         "id":5,
         "group_id":2,
         "name":"gps",
         "pivot":{
            "car_id":1,
            "feature_id":5
         },
         "group":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"interior"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "group_id":2,
         "name":"leather seats",
         "pivot":{
            "car_id":1,
            "feature_id":6
         },
         "group":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"interior"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Or I could use nested keys, `$myCollection->groupBy('group.name');` returns this:

```
{
   "paint":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "group_id":1,
         "name":"metallic",
         "pivot":{
            "car_id":1,
            "feature_id":1
         },
         "group":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"paint"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "group_id":1,
         "name":"blue",
         "pivot":{
            "car_id":1,
            "feature_id":2
         },
         "group":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"paint"
         }
      }
   ],
   "interior":[
      {
         "id":5,
         "group_id":2,
         "name":"gps",
         "pivot":{
            "car_id":1,
            "feature_id":5
         },
         "group":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"interior"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "group_id":2,
         "name":"leather seats",
         "pivot":{
            "car_id":1,
            "feature_id":6
         },
         "group":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"interior"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Now it's possible to loop over the output using a `@foreach()` in blade layout/component:

```
@foreach ($features as $feature)
    <h3>{{ $feature[0]->group->name }}</h3>
    @foreach ($feature as $item)
        <div>{{ $item->name }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```